# retrieving data from auto id database child

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, swift4

I'm kinda new on swift programming, my case is:

I have a database on firebase realtime "see picture", I want to retrieve the `firstName` and `lastName` data of a specific ID only.

[image]

for example: 
When i'm at login screen and logged in using this email: "**`ali_y_k@hotmail.com`**", and when going to the next screen i want to display the `firstName` and `lastName` of this `email` in the text fields showing on picture

[image: Log in Screen]

[image: HOme Screen]

I have tried several solutions but the problem always was I can't enter the random IDs child to fetch the `firstName` and `lastName`

there is what i tried: 
**First**

func retriveInfo () {

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("User_Informations")

databaseRef.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

    let firstName = snapshotValue["firstName"]!
    let lastName = snapshotValue["lastName"]!
    let email = snapshotValue["email"]!

    print(firstName,lastName,email)

  }
}
```

This is printing all data (`firstName`,`lastName`,`email`) from every id

---

**Second**

```
func retriveInfo() {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("User_Informations")


        databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for snap in snapshot.children {
                let userSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
                let uid = userSnap.key //the uid of each user
                let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject] //child data
                let firstName = userDict["firstName"] as! String
                let lastName = userDict["lastName"] as! String

                print("key = \(uid) First Name = \(firstName), Last Name = \(lastName)")
            }
        })
```

This will print every key "Id" and all the info

Thank You in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have childByAutoId you have to use query ordered and query equal.

```
let reference = Database.database().reference().child("User_Informations").queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
reference.queryEqual(toValue: "ali_y_k@hotmail.com").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
     let dictionary = snapshot.value as! [String : Any]
     let firstName = dictionary["firstName"]
     print(firstName)
}
```

Comment: You are right, sorry I was reading your answers and I did it by accident.

Comment: I can't undo it. If you edit your answer I will correct it.

Comment: Done. no hard feelings?

Comment: I did your solution and the print you write is printing the whole child with the key and its child, but when I ask to gave me the firstName value it prints nil, so it seems like it's not accessing the key child and fetch the firstName data .. hope that's clear :\

Comment: @AliYousef, then you can just use .childAdded and get the information from there. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the current user id after you login

```
let currentUserUid  = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("User_Informations/\(currentUserUid)") 
databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
}
```

Comment: it says 'Use of unresolved identifier 'currenUserId''

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to print the firstName value? I tried snapshot.value["firstName"] but doesn't work